# Javascript & HTML5 - Load .txt file splitting lines into different inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, line-breaks

I'm working on an online tool (a type of database) which users will be able to enter text data on different inputs, save on a txt.file and when they access the website again they can load the same file and have the data back on each input as it was before.

I found a good code and I did the first part, I can make a single file from different inputs. But the problem now is when I want to load the txt back to these inputs. How can I load into an input data that is on the second line, for example, of the txt file? Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value + ("\r\n") + document.getElementById("inputTextToSave2").value + ("\r\n") + document.getElementById("inputTextToSave3").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        //HERE IT SHOULD BE ONLY LINE 1//
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
        //HERE IT SHOULD BE ONLY LINE 2//
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave2").value = textFromFileLoaded;
        //HERE IT SHOULD BE ONLY LINE 3//
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave3").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:100px;height:100px"></textarea>
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave2" style="width:100px;height:100px"></textarea>
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave3" style="width:100px;height:100px"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad">
        <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Example: put "1" on the first area, "2" on the second, "3" on the third. Save. Load the file and it will show on the 3 boxes:
1
2
3
And it should show the results separately, as when it was saved.

I hope there is a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution, it was much easier than I thought. Just changed the final lines of the code to:

```
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        //HERE IT SHOULD BE ONLY LINE 1//
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        var text = textFromFileLoaded.split("\n");
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = text[0];
        //HERE IT SHOULD BE ONLY LINE 2//
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave2").value = text[1];
        //HERE IT SHOULD BE ONLY LINE 3//
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave3").value = text[2];
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```